# Please help me with the validation rule that it is not working during insert

Tags: validation, insert

```
NOT(
AND(
REGEX(Email, '^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,})+$'),
REGEX(Owner_1_Email_Address__c, '^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,})+$'),
REGEX(Owner_2_Email_Address__c, '^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,})+$'),
REGEX(Owner_3_Email_Address__c, '^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,})+$'),
REGEX(Owner_4_Email_Address__c, '^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,})+$'),
REGEX(Owner_5_Email_Address__c, '^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,})+$')
)
)
```

Comment: Using regex to try to validate email addresses is a fool's errand. That said, just like your previous question, **you need to include more details**. What does "not working" mean? What are examples of input that you think this validation rule should catch, but isn't (or is catching but shouldn't)? [Edit] your question to add details and answer those two clarifying questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, as Derek said, don't use regular expressions for email validation. Salesforce already enforces validation for email addresses. An invalid email address will cause an error such as: `INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Dancing Llama: invalid email address: example invalid email: [Email]`.

Just because you think an email address is invalid does not mean it is. The correct regular expression for validating an RFC 5322 email address looks like this:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Even this one is said to only be about 99.99% accurate, meaning there are still some possibly valid emails that could get flagged as invalid. Note, because of `\` being an escape character in formulas, too, you need a lot more backslashes...

Second, do not validate more than one field per validation rule. Even if you got this working correctly, the user would have to guess which field is causing the error, which is an unnecessarily hostile user experience.